# How can I reset values in Java?

Tags: java

It's difficult to me explain my question in one line, so I decide to explain the objective of my program. What the program what basically does, is change the background color using different colors. The first one is red, the second is green and the third is blue, the forth is surprise, and the fifth is white, also called default.

All of these sources can also be invoked using keyboard shortcuts. So first I create my `JFrame` class (The Marc), then the `JPanel` class (the lamina or panel) that contains the `JButton`s. But before creating it, there is some code to create a random color, it is the color that uses the surprise `JButton`, and here is my question.

In the program when I press the run button, and then click the surprise `JButton`, or use the keyboard, it paints the background with a random color (just as we want, for now all is correct).

If I press the button for a second time, the color is the same compared with the color that we obtained before. So, how can I can that JButton (surprise) show a new different random color the next time that I press it? In other words, how can I reset the values without reopening the program window?

Below is my code of the program and an image of how the program looks. I know that these is a lot of text, but I don't know how to describe the problem. To make the problem more clear I incorporated another program that has the objective that I want, but it has only one button (the button for the random color). I want that the surprise button works like the random button of the second program.

[Image of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omweW.png)

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Shortcut {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Open the Window when execute the program.
        shortMarc marc1=new shortMarc();

    }

}

//Create the Window.
class shortMarc extends JFrame{

    public shortMarc() {

        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Toolkit myscreen=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension screenSize=myscreen.getScreenSize();
        int heightScreen=screenSize.height;
        int widthScreen=screenSize.width;
        setSize(widthScreen/2, heightScreen/2);
        setLocation(widthScreen/4, heightScreen/4);
        setTitle("Hello My World!");

        shortLamina laminax=new shortLamina();
        add(laminax);

        Image icon1=myscreen.getImage("blackcircle.png");
        setIconImage(icon1);
    }

}

//Create a layer above the marc.
class shortLamina extends JPanel{

    public shortLamina() {

        //It creates an object that contain a random color to use it later on the program.
        int extra=10;
        int valorDado1=(int) ((Math.random()*256)+extra);
        int valorDado2=(int) ((Math.random()*256)+extra);
        int valorDado3=(int) ((Math.random()*256)+extra);
        if(valorDado1>255) {
            valorDado1=valorDado1-extra;
        }   
        if(valorDado2>255) {
            valorDado2=valorDado2-extra;
        }
        if(valorDado3>255) {
            valorDado3=valorDado3-extra;
        }
        Color randomcolor=new Color(valorDado1, valorDado2, valorDado3);

        // Create the user tangible objects. In this case the buttons.
        ActionColor actionGreen=new ActionColor("Green", new ImageIcon("green.png"), Color.GREEN, "It makes the background green (Ctrl G)");
        ActionColor actionBlue=new ActionColor("Blue", new ImageIcon("blue.png"), Color.BLUE, "It makes the background blue (Ctrl B)");
        ActionColor actionRed=new ActionColor("Red", new ImageIcon("red.png"), Color.RED, "It makes the background red (Ctrl R");
        ActionColor actionDefault=new ActionColor("Default", Color.WHITE, "It makes the background white, the default color (Ctrl D)");
        ActionColor actionRandom=new ActionColor("Sorprise", randomcolor, "It paint the background with a random color (Ctrl S)");

        JButton button1=new JButton(actionGreen);
        JButton button2=new JButton(actionBlue);
        JButton button3=new JButton(actionRed);
        JButton button4=new JButton(actionDefault);
        JButton button5=new JButton(actionRandom);

        add(button3);
        add(button1);
        add(button2);
        add(button5);
        add(button4);

        //Assign the key combinations.
        InputMap inputmap=getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);//Step 1. Create a InputMap. It indicates wherre is the source object.
        KeyStroke green_key=KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl G");// Step 2. Create a Key combination.
        KeyStroke blue_key=KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl B");
        KeyStroke red_key=KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl R");
        KeyStroke default_key=KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl D");
        KeyStroke random_key=KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl S");
        inputmap.put(green_key, "green_background"); //Step 3. Asign the key to the place of the sorce object.
        inputmap.put(blue_key, "blue_background");
        inputmap.put(red_key, "red_background");
        inputmap.put(default_key, "default_background");
        inputmap.put(random_key, "random_background");
        ActionMap actionmap=getActionMap();//Step 4. Create an object of type "action map" (instanciar) in spanish, to use it methods.
        actionmap.put("green_background", actionGreen);//Step 5. Asign the object of the key combination to the action created before using the method put of the actionmap object.
        actionmap.put("blue_background", actionBlue);
        actionmap.put("red_background", actionRed);
        actionmap.put("default_background", actionDefault);
        actionmap.put("random_background", actionRandom);

    }
    //Create the class that asign the constructor methods to the buttons.
    private class ActionColor extends AbstractAction{

        //Constructor method 1.
        public ActionColor(String nam, Icon icon, Color colorButton, String des) {

            putValue(Action.NAME, nam);
            putValue(Action.SMALL_ICON, icon);
            putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, des);
            putValue("background color", colorButton);

        }

        //Constructor method 2.
        public ActionColor(String nam, Color colorButton, String des) {

            putValue(Action.NAME, nam);
            putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, des);
            putValue("background color", colorButton);

        }

        //The listener class. It recive the instructions. 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Color c=(Color) getValue("background color");

            setBackground(c);

        }

    }
}
```

Here is my second program, that works as I want, but it has only one button. I would like to incorporate this button into my other program, but I don't know how. I hope it will make my question more clear.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ChangingColors {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        colorMarc marc1=new colorMarc();
    }

}

class colorMarc extends JFrame{

    public colorMarc() {

        setVisible(true);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Toolkit myscreen=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

        Dimension screenSize=myscreen.getScreenSize();

        int heightScreen=screenSize.height;

        int widthScreen=screenSize.width;

        setSize(736, 524);

        setLocation(widthScreen/4, heightScreen/4);

        setTitle("Hello Color!!!");



        //Lamina part.
        lamina4 mylamina=new lamina4();
        add(mylamina);


    }

}

//Lamina.
class lamina4 extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    JButton buttonToChange=new JButton("Change color");
    //int valorDado = (int)Math.random()*255+1;


    public lamina4() {

        add(buttonToChange);

        buttonToChange.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int extra=10;
        int valorDado1=(int) ((Math.random()*256)+extra);
        int valorDado2=(int) ((Math.random()*256)+extra);
        int valorDado3=(int) ((Math.random()*256)+extra);
        if(valorDado1>255) {
            valorDado1=valorDado1-extra;
        }   
        if(valorDado2>255) {
            valorDado2=valorDado2-extra;
        }
        if(valorDado3>255) {
            valorDado3=valorDado3-extra;
        }
        Color randomcolor=new Color(valorDado1, valorDado2, valorDado3);


        /*System.out.println(valorDado1);
        System.out.println(valorDado2);
        System.out.println(valorDado3);
        System.out.println();*/

        setBackground(randomcolor);

    }
}
```

Comment: Try something like this.  Put the random color calculations in a method so you can call a simple function like `Color randomColor = getRandomColor();`  

In your actionPerformed() method, test the name for "Sorprise" and generate a new random color to set the backgound e.g:

`if ("Sorprise".equals(getValue(Action.NAME)) setBackground(getRandomColor());`

Answer (score 0):

Your current code that generates the random color is this:

```
        int extra=10;
        int valorDado1=(int) ((Math.random()*256)+extra);
        int valorDado2=(int) ((Math.random()*256)+extra);
        int valorDado3=(int) ((Math.random()*256)+extra);
        if(valorDado1>255) {
            valorDado1=valorDado1-extra;
        }   
        if(valorDado2>255) {
            valorDado2=valorDado2-extra;
        }
        if(valorDado3>255) {
            valorDado3=valorDado3-extra;
        }
        Color randomcolor=new Color(valorDado1, valorDado2, valorDado3);
```

Now let's focus on these lines of code:

```
int valorDado1=(int) ((Math.random()*256)+extra);
int valorDado2=(int) ((Math.random()*256)+extra);
int valorDado3=(int) ((Math.random()*256)+extra);
```

...and more specifically this:

```
((Math.random()*256)+extra);
```

All the above does is pick a number between 10 and 266. So since `valorDado1`, `valorDado2`, and `valorDado3`are most likely are less than 255, you need to change

```
if(valorDado1>255) {
    valorDado1=valorDado1-extra;
}   
if(valorDado2>255) {
    valorDado2=valorDado2-extra;
}
if(valorDado3>255) {
    valorDado3=valorDado3-extra;
}
```

to

```
if(valorDado1<=255) {
    valorDado1=valorDado1-extra;
}   
if(valorDado2<=255) {
    valorDado2=valorDado2-extra;
}
if(valorDado3<=255) {
    valorDado3=valorDado3-extra;
}
```

(notice the comparison operator has changed)

Comment: I don't think that this can resolve the problem, I added the extra value to make the random color most white, because it commonly generate me pretty darker colors. It only change the color, but my question is very different. I think that the answer could be in the actionPerformed Method (the listener). I have another program, that works pretty god, but it has only one button, and I want to added in my program... let me upgrade my question and add the other program.

Comment: Thanks, for answer, I publish my second program. I want that the Surprise Button of the first program works like the random button of the second program. :) And again thanks for dedicate time to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. To do that, I need to stablish the random color outside of the constructor method of the lamina. If you don't do that, and set the random color in the constructor, the coloralways is the same at least you close and reopen the program. The solution is create another Abstract Action Class.

The final code is this:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Shortcut {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Open the Window when execute the program.
        shortMarc marc1=new shortMarc();

    }

}

//Create the Window.
class shortMarc extends JFrame{

    public shortMarc() {

        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        shortLamina laminax=new shortLamina();
        add(laminax);

        Toolkit myscreen=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension screenSize=myscreen.getScreenSize();
        int heightScreen=screenSize.height;
        int widthScreen=screenSize.width;
        setSize(widthScreen/2, heightScreen/2);
        setLocation(widthScreen/4, heightScreen/4);
        setTitle("Changing colors game!");



        Image icon1=myscreen.getImage("blackcircle.png");
        setIconImage(icon1);
    }

}

//Create a layer above the marc.
class shortLamina extends JPanel{

    public shortLamina() {

        //It creates an object that contain a random color to use it later on the program.
        int extra=10;
        int valorDado1=(int) ((Math.random()*256)+extra);
        int valorDado2=(int) ((Math.random()*256)+extra);
        int valorDado3=(int) ((Math.random()*256)+extra);
        if(valorDado1>255) {
            valorDado1=valorDado1-extra;
        }   
        if(valorDado2>255) {
            valorDado2=valorDado2-extra;
        }
        if(valorDado3>255) {
            valorDado3=valorDado3-extra;
        }
        Color randomcolor=new Color(valorDado1, valorDado2, valorDado3);

        // Create the user tangible objects. In this case the buttons.
        ActionColor actionGreen=new ActionColor("Green", new ImageIcon("green.png"), Color.GREEN, "It makes the background green (Ctrl G)");
        ActionColor actionBlue=new ActionColor("Blue", new ImageIcon("blue.png"), Color.BLUE, "It makes the background blue (Ctrl B)");
        ActionColor actionRed=new ActionColor("Red", new ImageIcon("red.png"), Color.RED, "It makes the background red (Ctrl R");
        ActionColor actionDefault=new ActionColor("Default", Color.WHITE, "It makes the background white, the default color (Ctrl D)");
        ActionRandom actionRandom=new ActionRandom("Random", randomcolor, "It paint the background with a random color (Ctrl X, Ctrl S)");

        JButton button1=new JButton(actionGreen);
        JButton button2=new JButton(actionBlue);
        JButton button3=new JButton(actionRed);
        JButton button4=new JButton(actionDefault);
        JButton button5=new JButton(actionRandom);

        add(button3);
        add(button1);
        add(button2);
        add(button5);
        add(button4);

        //Assign the key combinations.
        InputMap inputmap=getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);//Step 1. Create a InputMap. It indicates wherre is the source object.
        KeyStroke green_key=KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl G");// Step 2. Create a Key combination.
        KeyStroke blue_key=KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl B");
        KeyStroke red_key=KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl R");
        KeyStroke default_key=KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl D");
        KeyStroke random_key=KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl X");
        KeyStroke random_key2=KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl S");
        inputmap.put(green_key, "green_background"); //Step 3. Asign the key to the place of the sorce object.
        inputmap.put(blue_key, "blue_background");
        inputmap.put(red_key, "red_background");
        inputmap.put(default_key, "default_background");
        inputmap.put(random_key, "random_background");
        inputmap.put(random_key2, "random_background");
        ActionMap actionmap=getActionMap();//Step 4. Create an object of type "action map" (instanciar) in spanish, to use it methods.
        actionmap.put("green_background", actionGreen);//Step 5. Asign the object of the key combination to the action created before using the method put of the actionmap object.
        actionmap.put("blue_background", actionBlue);
        actionmap.put("red_background", actionRed);
        actionmap.put("default_background", actionDefault);
        actionmap.put("random_background", actionRandom);

    }
    //Create the class that asign the constructor methods to the buttons.
    private class ActionColor extends AbstractAction{

        //Constructor method 1.
        public ActionColor(String nam, Icon icon, Color colorButton, String des) {

            putValue(Action.NAME, nam);
            putValue(Action.SMALL_ICON, icon);
            putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, des);
            putValue("background color", colorButton);

        }

        //Constructor method 2.
        public ActionColor(String nam, Color colorButton, String des) {

            putValue(Action.NAME, nam);
            putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, des);
            putValue("background color", colorButton);

        }

        //The listener class. It recive the instructions. 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Color c=(Color) getValue("background color");

            setBackground(c);

        }

    }

    private class ActionRandom extends AbstractAction{

        public ActionRandom(String nam, Color colorButton, String des) {

            putValue(Action.NAME, nam);
            putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, des);
            putValue("background color", colorButton);

        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int extra=10;
            int valorDado1=(int) ((Math.random()*256)+extra);
            int valorDado2=(int) ((Math.random()*256)+extra);
            int valorDado3=(int) ((Math.random()*256)+extra);
            if(valorDado1>255) {
                valorDado1=valorDado1-extra;
            }   
            if(valorDado2>255) {
                valorDado2=valorDado2-extra;
            }
            if(valorDado3>255) {
                valorDado3=valorDado3-extra;
            }
            Color randomcolor=new Color(valorDado1, valorDado2, valorDado3);


            /*System.out.println(valorDado1);
            System.out.println(valorDado2);
            System.out.println(valorDado3);
            System.out.println();*/

            setBackground(randomcolor);


        }


    }

}
```